# Is it possible to hide youtube's big red play button with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Quick example of the code I'm using at the moment to create my YouTube iframe:

```
player = new YT.Player('[PLAYER ID]', {
  height: '300',
  width: '480',
  videoId: '[VIDEO ID]',
  playerVars: { 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
});
```

It's all working great so far, it's loading the video fine without controls or the info strip and I'm 'manually' playing the video using javascript.

The problem is that there's now no need for the big red 'play' button that is momentarily displayed as the video's starting.

[image]

Is there any way I can get rid of this? I've looked through the documentation and can't find a suitable parameter that would allow me to hide it.

Answer (score 4):

I found it not possible. So the only way to hide Play button is to place video image above the video which can be fetched from youtube as follow.
Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

But once you add the overlay, clicking on the screen instead of control will not play the video, To do this add the following jQuery which plays the video

```
jQuery('#overlay').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).hide();
  jQuery('#youtube_id').get(0).playVideo();
});
```

Comment: This, too, would be against the terms of service, as you cannot overlay anything on the video yourself.

Comment: This is not true. The big red replay button can be rid of, as seen in the [jwplayer.js](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed) and [video.js](https://static.bini.io/cus-videos/) YouTube wrappers. Both of these popular javascript libraries rely on YouTube iFrame API for YouTube embeds. So I don't think they use some black magic.

Comment: @stillenat `video.js` for example does use "black magic". It simply fetches one of the standard thumbnail images and inserts such an overlay into the DOM. It only inserts the youtube video into the DOM once you press play and even then it does not use the YouTube iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images. The default thumbnail image (ie. one of `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) is:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url similar to the HQ:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

All of the above urls are available over https too. Just change `http` to `https` in any of the above urls. Additionally, the slightly shorter hostname `i3.ytimg.com` works in place of `img.youtube.com` in the example urls above.

Alternatively, you can use the [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) or the older [YouTube API v2.0](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html) to get thumbnail images.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that's gone into this answer but the issue is that the images are unwanted. I'd ideally like to get rid of them.

Comment: The two parameters I found useful are:

    showinfo=0
    controls=0
    autohide=1

`showinfo=0` makes sure the video does not display the title on the top of the video frame. `controls=0` hides the bottom bar with the play button, volume, etc. `autohide=1` hides the controls until you hover over them, which is probably the most useful. 

All the official docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Comment: I know mate, I appreciate that but I've tried that already; those parameters are already in place.

Comment: Removing the “play on youtube” overlay manually is against the Terms of Service. Check my new answer

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution to what the OP is asking.