# How to edit the inside of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

On my tumblr page 8fuuntvtest.tumblr.com, which is just the testing page at the moment, I have a list on the right with videos, and when you click on the name of the video it appears to the left.
Aesthetically, though, I don't like to have the play button and the header thing on the player list. So I want to target the iframe inside the div .postList and hide the play button (.ytp-large-play-button) and the header (.html-info-bar). 
I am not sure how to approach this though as nothing seems to edit the inside of the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a repeat of this question to me.

[Is it possible to hide youtube's big red play button with a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596551/is-it-possible-to-hide-youtubes-big-red-play-button-with-a-parameter)

You can't hide the play button, but if that thumbnail is only supposed to be static just load in the video image instead. It will be static with no play buttons or toolbars.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how I will do this, as I would have to add the image manually every singe time, but that, at least, show me my opportunities.