# Youtube play button issue

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have embedded a YouTube video on my Shopify store, but as we know it doesn't auto play on mobiles and tabs so I have used YouTube API to play it on external click as I don't like the big red button
But cant make it disappear, issue is I already have text positioned over the video so cant use an overlay image like most of solutions.

My code:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div id="bucklesburyVideo"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('bucklesburyVideo', {
            playerVars: {
                'playlist': 'f8BxdOvj1Ho',
                'loop': 1,
                'autoplay': 1,
                'controls': 0,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'wmode': 'opaque'
            },
            videoId: 'f8BxdOvj1Ho',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
        var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            player.playVideo();
        });

        var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and its [player parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), there is no instruction or method there that can show you on how to hide the big red play button of the YouTube. So what can I suggest you is to use a custom CSS to hide or adjust the location of the Play button.

Check this [thread](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/) if it can help you.

For more information, check the other solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596551).